# JAX-WS For Json request and response

Tags: java, json, web-services, soap

I want to write a web service using SOAP where the request/response should be in json format instead of xml format.

I tried using "`@BindingType(JSONBindingID.JSON_BINDING)`" using the  [reference](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/json/)  and ended up with error `Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Wrong binding ID: https://jax-ws-commons.dev.java.net/json/`

Can anybody provide me with a simple (SOAP-JSON)example other than the above reference.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please look at the example at below link
https://code.google.com/p/jsonwebservice/wiki/GettingStarted for json request/response to jax-ws

Comment: really old demo on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/jsonwebservice/wiki/GettingStarted) and make sure there is no dependency problem

Comment: Axis-2 having support for that. If you can move to axis-2 you can try this.
https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/json_support.html